# How to enable plugin trace logs programatically / via SDK

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

I know how to enable plugin trace logs via UI - i.e.

[image: UI of CRM - System settings/Customizations/Plug-in and custom workflow activity tracking]

Is there a way how to do it programatically (via SDK call) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, [Plugin Trace Viewer for XrmToolBox](http://ptv.xrmtoolbox.com/) has the option to change the logging level.

From the source code, it should be an update to the `organization` entity, field `plugintracelogsetting` (optionset with the following options: Off = 0, Exception = 1, All = 2)

The `organization` entity should have only a single record, so you do a `RetrieveMultiple` and check the first result in order to get the Id for the entity update.

Comment: Good find. I searched for that setting in this PFE solution but could not find: https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=orgdborgsettings